# Integrate Kubernetes and SDN?

Tags: kubernetes, sdn, openflow, ryu

I'm using Kubernetes to build a platform, that can control multiple Raspberry PIs. And let those PIs cooperate with each other to achieve some complex application, such like computing vision.

Because the PIs may moving, hence the network topology change often. I wondering is it possible that I integrate the SDN and Kubernetes, and make the network config more flexible.

I am the newbie of SDN, not sure is this idea practical. And if the answer is yes, then which SDN project is better to implement? (Ryu? OpenContrail?) Does it has a GUI can let me see how the devices connected (visualization graph)?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not enough reputation to add comment,

I think first you must to know the how the sdn controller and openflow, and second to realize the CNI of kubernetes, you can build own network like sdn on this, but you need to know how it working and this spec

what controller like ryu or onos or opendaylight good? I will say that you can use which one you like or you use it better

Answer (score 0):

One of CNI project - [linen-cni](https://github.com/John-Lin/linen-cni) can work with OpenFlow controller (e.g ONOS)
You can try the project and figure out what you are looking for.